# как обновить Label с помощью запроса, без обновления страницы раз в 2 сек?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-webforms

на `asp.net` странице есть `Label`, в котором должна обновляться информация каждые 2 секунды без обновления страницы. Данные должны будут браться из  таблицы SQL запроса.

Видел примеры по клику кнопки например с помощью JS, а по таймеру как это сделать, чтобы срабатывал запрос и обновлял значение в `Label`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот таймер

```
       Timer t = new Timer();//инициализация 
       t.Interval = 2000; // интервал в миллисекундах 
       t.Enabled = true; // таймер включен 

       t.Tick += DoSomeThink; метод который будет срабатывать 
        t.Start();// запускаем таймер
```

вот метод

```
private void DoSomeThink(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = @"Прошло 2 секунды";
        }
```

Вот JavaScript

```
 window.onload = function () {
                setInterval(() => {

                //ваш код тут обрашайтесь к label

                }, 2000);

            }
```

Comment: не совсем понял. получается в методе DoSomeThink я присвою то, что мне нужно с помощью запроса, в "//ваш код тут" у меня что пойдет? таймер?

Comment: это java Script если он подерживается то пойдет

Comment: JS поддерживается, в итоге я добавил таймер на page_load, запилил метод, в котором я присвоил леблу значение из таблицы по sql запросу, в JS не понимаю что писать внутрь, вообще мало работал с ним, какое волшебное слово сказать, чтобы все заработало?

Comment: исправил код JavaScripta посмотрите он запустится сразу при загрузке

Comment: видимо `document.getElementById(prefix+"lblLastScanned").value= document.body.lblLastScanned;` это чушь собачья? потому что работать это не хочет

Comment: Тогда используйте таймер, работает функция или нет посмотрите в консоле   `console.log("It Works"); закиньте в тело функции`

Comment: в консоль всё пишет, работает, с помощью JS я же могу обратиться и вызывать функцию c#? которая берет и записывает в Label мою переменную?

Comment: например я обращусь к лейблу в JS, а у самого элемента Label поставлю OnPreRender="UpdateLabel"

Comment: Да можно если использовать CEFsharp , можно скорее и по другому вобшем логика такая вам надо сделать так чтобы ваша программа постоянно смотрела в консоль и ждала какое то ключевое слово для запуска `UpdateLabel`

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за подсказку и наводку. Я решил реализовать этот функционал через `UpdatePanel` и `Timer`

Разметка:

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer_Tick1" Enabled="true" Interval="10000"/>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
    <tr>
        <td>
             <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server" RenderMode="Inline" UpdateMode="Conditional">
             <ContentTemplate><asp:Label ID="lblLastScanned" Style="margin-left: 15px; word-wrap: break-word" runat="server"/>
             </ContentTemplate>
                 <triggers>
                           <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" />
                 </triggers>
          </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

далее я методом возвращаю строчку:

```
private string UpdateLabel()
{
    //code path
    return result;
}
protected void Timer_Tick1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblLastScanned.Text = UpdateLabel();
    }
```